# Ionic- Referencing Cordova Plugin from Index.html

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Fairly new to Ionic. I'm trying to import Zappar from ZapWorks into my Ionic project.
After obtaining the required plugin, I installed it via `cordova plugin add <path>`.

However, the function provided isn't available via `window.launchZappar()`. My thinking is that even though I added the plugin via `cordova plugin add` command, I still have to import the necessary `*.js` file but then I can't seem to reference the `*.js` file in my `/plugins` folder

Answer (score 1):

Two thing to note:

1. Issue could be that you are calling its to earlier. Plugins are available after [platformready](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready) event.
2. From what I see you plugin is working on mobile only so if you are testing in browser it wont work.